# Map data points to colormap with seaborn.swarmplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to generate a seaborn.swarmplot, in which the color of single datapoints is mapped to a color map.

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
In[48]:df
Out[48]: 
      a  c   Key
   0  1  12  1st
   1  4  35  2nd
   2  5  12  2nd
   3  6  46  1st
   4  3  78  1st
   5  4  45  2nd
   6  5  34  1st
   7  6  70  2nd
```

I generate a swarmplot with the following code:

```
sns.swarmplot(x='Key', y = 'a',  s=20, data = df)
```

And get a plot like this:

[Swarmplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4h3V.png)

Now, I would like the datapoints to map to a colormap, which would represent the values according to column 'c' of the DataFrame.

I tried to add 'hue = 'c' to the code and get the following:

```
sns.swarmplot(x='Key', y = 'a',  hue='c',s=20, data = df)
```

[Swarmplot with 'hue'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFhjX.png)

This kind of goes into the direction I want it, but I'd much rather prefer to have the color map to a color map, so that low 'c' values would for example be light-green and the higher the 'c' value get the darker the green gets.

As a legend I would like to have a gradient.

Help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Solution without colorbar

The solution without colorbar is rather easy. You need to create a `palette` of colors (with as many colors as values) and supply it to the `swarmplot` using the `palette` argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
print sns.__version__ # swarmplot requires version 0.7.1

# Reconstruct the dataframe from the question (the hardest part)
a = [1,4,5,6,3,4,5,6]
c = [12,35,12,46,78,45,34,70]
key = [1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2]
key = ["{k}{a}".format(k=k, a={1:"st", 2:"nd"}[k]) for k in key]
df  =pd.DataFrame({"a":a, "c":c, "Key":key})

palette = sns.light_palette("seagreen", reverse=False,  n_colors=len(c) )
sns.swarmplot(x='Key', y = 'a',  hue='c',s=20, data = df, palette=palette)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Solution with colorbar

The solution with colorbar requires more work. 
We need to construct a colormap from the seaborn palette, normalize this colormap and create a dictionary of colors corresponding to the respective colors from the `df["c"]` dataframe column. We then provide this dictionary to the `swarmplot` using again the `palette` keyword.

We also need to remove the automatically generated, but useless legend and then create a new axes in the plot to place the colorbar.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

import seaborn as sns

# recreate the dataframe
a = [1,4,5,6,3,4,5,6]
c = [12,35,12,46,78,45,34,70]
key = [1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2]
key = ["{k}{a}".format(k=k, a={1:"st", 2:"nd"}[k]) for k in key]
df  =pd.DataFrame({"a":a, "c":c, "Key":key})

#Create a matplotlib colormap from the sns seagreen color palette
cmap    = sns.light_palette("seagreen", reverse=False, as_cmap=True )
# Normalize to the range of possible values from df["c"]
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=df["c"].min(), vmax=df["c"].max())
# create a color dictionary (value in c : color from colormap) 
colors = {}
for cval in df["c"]:
    colors.update({cval : cmap(norm(cval))})

#create a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.8))
#plot the swarmplot with the colors dictionary as palette
m = sns.swarmplot(x='Key', y = 'a',  hue="c", s=20, data = df, palette = colors)
# remove the legend, because we want to set a colorbar instead
plt.gca().legend_.remove()

## create colorbar ##
divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
ax_cb = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
cb1 = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax_cb, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=norm,
                                orientation='vertical')
cb1.set_label('Some Units')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much, figuring out the code for the colorbar would probably have taken me three days!

Comment: @Ozzycalifornia: If you find this answer useful you can upvote it.

Comment: I did, but I my reputation is too low. It says, the upvote is being recorded but not displayed. Sorry, but a million thanks again!!

Comment: Short question: (Why? ) Is the reformatting of the 'Key' column necessary? I don't understand what it changes. If you have time a very short response would be great! Thanks again!!

Comment: In your code the `Key` column contains strings like `'1st'`. Because I did not have your dataframe at hand, I needed to write it myself and this was the easiest way for me. This is really just to get the same dataframe as you already have, so no need to worry about it. You could of course directly type in the strings in a list if you want.