# seaborn swarmplot with markers for hue (categories) and colormap for values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a [`seaborn.swarmplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html#seaborn.swarmplot) with categories (hue) represented as markers, while the color of the scatterplots defines the value of an additional column.

I found [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821782/6345518) to be quite similar, but instead I'd like to add another column to my dataframe, let's call it `cat` for a categoric variable, which is set as `hue='cat'` while the colormap is defined via the column `c`. Instead of colored categories, I want the categories to be marked with **markers**, f.i. `markers=['x', 'o', 'd']`. I adapted the above mentioned answer to implement at least the colormap to depend on c but to be also mapped by the category, but the **setting a marker for each category still fails**:

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colorbar
import matplotlib.colors
import matplotlib.cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

import seaborn as sns

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'a': [1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
          'c': [12, 35, 12, 46, 78, 45, 34, 70], 
          'cat': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
          'key': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]}
)

# Create a matplotlib colormap from the sns seagreen color palette
cmap = sns.light_palette("seagreen", reverse=False, as_cmap=True)
# Normalize to the range of possible values from df["c"]
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=df["c"].min(), vmax=df["c"].max())
# create a color dictionary (value in c : color from colormap) 
colors = {}
for cat, cval in zip(df['cat'], df["c"]):
    colors.update({'{0}-{1}'.format(cat, cval) : cmap(norm(cval))})
# save cat-col key as new reformed cat col:
df['cat-color'] = list(colors.keys())

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,2.8))
# plot the swarmplot with the colors dictionary as palette
m = sns.swarmplot(x='key', y='a', hue="cat-color", s=12, data=df, 
                  palette=colors, markers=['x', 'o', 'd'])

## create colorbar ##
divider = make_axes_locatable(plt.gca())
ax_cb = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
cb1 = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    ax_cb, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, orientation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Any idea how to integrate the markers and how to make the color only dependent on `c` **and not on `cat`**?
I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52909297/6345518) which deals with markers, but I can't see any way to combine it to have markers and colors **independently**.